# Android show HTTP error code in a Toast

Tags: android, toast, status, android-ksoap2

Logic scheme:

[image]

What I need is to show error code + some "sorry" text in a Toast.
But I get the status code in a class that is being called in `call` in `doInBackground` in `Async Task` called by button tap on the `Activity`.

What is the way to push the received status code backwards up to the Activity?:

```
try {
            retHeaders = connection.getResponseProperties();
            for (int i = 0; i < retHeaders.size(); i++) {
                HeaderProperty hp = (HeaderProperty)retHeaders.get(i);
                // HTTP response code has null key
                if (null == hp.getKey()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // If we know the size of the response, we should use the size to initiate vars
                if (hp.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("content-length") ) {
                    if ( hp.getValue() != null ) {
                        try {
                            contentLength = Integer.parseInt( hp.getValue() );
                        } catch ( NumberFormatException nfe ) {
                            contentLength = 8192;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Check the content-type header to see if we're getting back XML, in case of a
                // SOAP fault on 500 codes
                if (hp.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Content-Type")
                        && hp.getValue().contains("xml")) {
                    xmlContent = true;
                }

                // ignoring case since users found that all smaller case is used on some server
                // and even if it is wrong according to spec, we rather have it work..
                if (hp.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("Content-Encoding")
                     && hp.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                    gZippedContent = true;
                }
            }

            //first check the response code....
            if (status != 200) {

                // here to put Toast call

               throw new HttpResponseException("HTTP request failed, HTTP status: " + status, status);
            }
}
```

Comment: show both `Toast` and `Activity switching` in `onPostExecute(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

just do it

```
  if (status != 200) {

            // here to put Toast call
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"score Submitted  successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 throw new HttpResponseException("HTTP request failed, HTTP status: " + status, status);

 }else{

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Occured: "+status,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
```

Comment: and nothing new happens

Answer (score 0):

In `onPostExecute(...)` check the status code depending on it do your work

```
if (status != 200) {
   // here to put the Toast "Sorry"
} else {
  // switch to another activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a callback interface between your AsyncTask and Activity to pass data.

In AsyncTask:

```
public AsyncTask(Activity activity) {
    // Attach your activity to AsyncTask
    mActivity = activity;
}

public interface OnAsyncTaskCompletedListener {
    void onAsyncTaskCompleted({returned data});
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute({returned data}) {
    if (mActivity != null) mActivity.onAsyncTaskCompleted({returned data});
}
```

Then you implement OnAsyncTaskCompletedListener in your Activity class:

```
@Override
public void onAsyncTaskCompleted({returned data}) { //show toast }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways !

1. *Use* [**onPostExecute()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) and check the status code
2. *Use* [**OnProgressUpdate()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) and check the status code

---

***Sample::***

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        Button btn;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            // detect the view that was "clicked"
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                new LongOperation().execute("");
                break;
            }
        }

        private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: my AsyncTaskActivity does not extend Activity and is in a separate class, not that, where Dialog should be. It is shown on a scheme.

Comment: @IvanFazaniuk ... If your AsyncTask is in different Class, You can pass the references while calling the async task and update the views as i showed in answer .... Implementation still remains the same - Just you need to pass the references